# iOS CLLocation Order In Which Code is Run

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocation, cllocationdistance

I have managed to get the co-ordinates for 2 cities using `GLGeocoder geocodeAddressString`

Having retrieved this 2 city co-ordinates from their names, I want to calculate the distance between them. However Im facing an issue in that the `CLLocationDistance` runs before the `geocodeAddressString`.

How do i ensure the distance is only calculated AFTER the city locations have?

Please see my code below:

```
__block CLLocation *depLocation;
__block CLLocation *arrLocation;

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Birmingham" completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
    {

        depLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
                       initWithLatitude:aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude
                       longitude:aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude];

    }
}];

CLGeocoder *geocoder2 = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder2 geocodeAddressString:@"Amritsar" completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks2, NSError* error){
    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark2 in placemarks2)
    {

        arrLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
                       initWithLatitude:aPlacemark2.location.coordinate.latitude
                       longitude:aPlacemark2.location.coordinate.longitude];

    }
}];

CLLocationDistance distanceXYZ = [depLocation distanceFromLocation:arrLocation];
NSString *distanceLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance to point %4.0f m.", distanceXYZ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer would be to nest all their completion blocks. Copy all the `geoCoder2` stuff and put it in `geocoder` completion block, then copy `distanceXYZ` and `distanceLabel` in to the completion block of `geocoder2`

Comment: Awesome that worked - not sure why that didn't occur to me. Cheers.

Comment: No worries, the long answer would be to `KVO` `depLocation` and `arrLocation`, then calculate the disntace once they had been instantiated.